# R markdown (html_pretty) does not show "not equal" symbol properly

Tags: html, r-markdown

I found that "html_pretty" output does not properly show the unequal math symbol.

The following is the minimal reproducible example for it.

```
---
title: "example"
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: architect
    highlight: github
    math: katex
---

$$
\mu \neq \mu_0
$$
```

This shows
[image]

However, the regular "html_document" format works, showing $\noteq$ as we want.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

$$
\mu \neq \mu_0
$$
```

Do you have any idea about the reason? How do I use the unequal symbol in "html_pretty" format?

Comment: It's not `pretty` so much; it's the theme `architect` with `pretty`. It doesn't happen with `leonids`.  I just saw your question today; I am going to try to figure this out!

Comment: This wasn't even worthy of putting as an answer—although that's what this is. Drop the output `math: katex` from your YAML. It's not needed and it's not playing well with the theme and output. You usually won't need anything like this for an HTML-based output.

Comment: @Kat Thanks! That worked, but it changed the math font. To preserve it, I add `mathfont: Arial` in my YAML.